# How to write a paginator which would set a default page depending on the current date?

Tags: django, pagination, django-pagination

I have a  huge list of lessons ordered by the date. I want to include paginator so it would always set default page on a current date(if such lessons exists, and if not the nearest future lessons).Is it even possible to do?

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Lesson
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

lesson_list = Lesson.objects.all().order_by('datetime')
paginator = Paginator(user_list, 10)
```

Comment: Just to clarify - you want a queryset of Lesson objects which are ordered: (1) today's date, and then (2) all other dates in descending order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate your QuerySet with a [conditional expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) based on whether or not the `Lesson` is today, and then use that annotation to sort your QuerySet.

```py
from datetime import date  # for typing
from django.db.models import BooleanField, Case, Value, When
from django.utils import timezone

current_date: date = timezone.now().date()

lesson_list = Lesson.objects.annotate(
    lesson_today=Case(
        When(datetime__date=current_date, then=Value(True)),
        default=Value(False),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
).order_by('-lesson_today', '-datetime')
```

- Get the current datetime by using Django's [built-in timezone utility](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/timezones/#concepts). Use [`.date()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) to get a date object from the datetime object.
- [`annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the QuerySet with a field named `lesson_today`.
- The value of `lesson_today` is a boolean [`Case()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) where `Lesson.datetime` has a year, month and day that matches the current date. Use the [`__date`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#date) subscript to ensure we're not trying to match on the hour, minute and second components of the `DateTimeField`.
- Ordering by `-lesson_today` first means that objects where `lesson_today=True` are sorted first. The remaining objects are then sorted in reverse chronological order (e.g. future lessons).